# Can't figure out what's wrong with my code :\ (Array subtraction in C)

Tags: c, arrays

```
void signalclear(int noise[], int star[], int clear[]) {
 int i = 0;
 int j = 0;
  while (clear[i] != -1) {
      if (star[j] == -1) {
        j = 0;
       }
      if (noise[i] == -1) {
        clear[i] = -1;
        break;
       }
      clear[i] = noise[i] - star[j];
      i++;
      j++;
    }
}
```

Its supposed to subtract `star[]` from `noise[]` until it hits `-1`, star[] is shorter so it has to restart from its beginning until `noise[]` hits `-1`, then it will stop.

The input looks like this, but i'm using experimental values right now, you can see them below.

```
(noise[])
382 450 402 490 592 652 712 832 422 370 362 450 512 512 512 532 683 694 700 
712 789 509 480 540 512 469 450 412 402 422 462 522 -1

(star[])
120 120 140 160 200 260 320 440 160 40 100 120 120 -1
```

So right now it stops after it hits the first -1 here `{10,0,20,-1}` but it should just restart and keep substracting until the other sequence hits -1.

```
ERROR: signalclear({30,10,40,40,20,30,30,30,-1},{10,0,20,-1},{...}) // this sequence of numbers is only for testing.
Expected Result: {...} = {20,10,20,30,20,10,20,30,-1}
My Result: {...} = {20,10,20,30,-1}
```

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, not at 1. Otherwise your code looks more or less correct. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: _the "star" one is shorter so it has to restart from its beginning until "noise" hits '-1', then it will stop._ Not sure if I understood this correctly. Please provide an example. Don't answer in a comment but [edit]  your question.

Comment: The array clear[ ] ist not returned!

Comment: @Mike, I don't think the array `clear[]` needs to be returned, @stan Marsh has specified the return type of the function to be `void`

Comment: @Stan Marsh, what is the value of `clear[]`? it seems as if you are subtracting values of `clear[]` from `noise[]` even before assigning something to it. if you're assigning it something before passing it to the function, then fine. Else, do cross-check it once.

Comment: and what is the current output you're getting? Posting this would be making it easier for the answerers to solve what's causing the problem.

Comment: What should `clear` contain after the call to `signalclear` with the input you have provided?

Comment: @Rai Sorry, i fixed it, its  clear[i] = noise[i] - star[i];

Comment: Okay that's great. So the error is solved then?

Comment: @Rai Well not exactly, but it's working better than before, for some reason it still doesnt stop after it hits -1

Comment: by the way @stan marsh, what should hit -1? `clear` or `star`

Comment: because both `clear` and `star` are not being decremented or affected in anyway inside the `while`. so the loop will go on forever, because the values of those 2 never reach -1

Comment: @Rai noise and star should hit -1

Comment: @Rai I added the values of noise[] and star[] above, there's -1 at the end of those two sequences.

Comment: oh sorry buddy. never noticed. My bad.

Comment: check my answer which i just posted. should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

1. Your indexing is starting from `1` instead of `0`.
2. > *The "star" one is shorter so it has to restart from its beginning
   >   until "noise" hits '-1', then it will stop*.

   This you are not handling correctly.

If I understood your problem correctly. The below code should do what you have expected.

```
void signalclear(int noise[64], int star[64], int clear[64]) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < 64) {

            if (star[j] == -1) {
               j = 0; //Reset the j to start from the beginning.
            }

            if (noise[i] == -1) {
              clear[i] = -1;
              break;
            }

           clear[i] = noise[i] - star[j];
           i++;
           j++;
        }
   }
```

This is how I call from `main`

```
void main()
{
    int noise[64] = {30,10,40,40,20,30,30,30,-1};
    int star[64] = {10,0,20,-1};
    int clear [64];

    signalclear(noise,star,clear);

    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<64 && clear[i-1] != -1; i++)
    printf("%d ", clear[i]);
}
```

Output:`20 10 20 30 20 10 20 30 -1`

Comment: This is my output: `ERROR: signalclear({20,20,20,20,-1},{0,5,10,15,-1},{...})
        expected result: {...} = {20,15,10,5,-1}
        my result: {...} = {20,15,10,5,-1047986171,4199136,4199136,0,4203264,6422240,...}` so for some reason it still doesnt stop after -1 :\

Comment: @StanMarsh It is because you are printing the resulted array from `0` to `63`. Since your resulted array will contain garbage value from 4th index.

Comment: @StanMarsh: In the question, you show sample data of 382, 450,… for `noise` and 120, 120,… for `star`. Subtracting these would produce 262, 350,… This does not match your comment above, which shows 20, 15,… for expected results. Also, your comment above shows your results as both 20, 20,… in one message and 20, 15,… in another. So you are being unclear and contradictory in your statements about what the data is, what the observed results are, and what the expected results are. Either give **one** set of data and results, or **clearly label** different sets of data so readers can follow them.

Comment: @kiranBiradar I edited my code, could you take one last look at it please? It wont go further now, but it's still not perfect :\

Comment: @StanMarsh  `while (clear[i] != -1)` this wrong and it should be `while (i < 64)`

Comment: @kiranBiradar It works now perfectly, thank you, you're awesome! :) I only had to change it to `while (clear[i-1] != -1)` not sure why exactly but it worked haha